# Check PostgreSQL table column for value and return boolean

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql

I am just learning SQL and apologize if this is repetitive, but I have searched and not found an answer. Writing in python with a PostgreSQL DB.

I want to check a table in my database to see if the "Port" column contains a specific location. I can do this interactively, but it returns a table result, eg:

```
select exists(select 1 from ref_locations where "Port"='ORAN');
```

it returns:

```
exists
-------
t
(1 row)
```

... I want it to return JUST a boolean value, and I want to do it in my python script. In my python script I have:

```
exists = False
cnx.execute("""select exists(select 1 from ref_locations where "Port"='BAKU');""")
print "Exists: ",exists
```

but exists is always filled with False. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `print "Exists: ",exists` your exists variable is not changed by the result of the query. You need to retrieve the result from the query, and assign it to your variable. There probably is some function in your cursor, like `exists = cnx.get_result();`

Comment: Thank you! Great answers. And at least in the process of my working through this, I realized that since I am testing many words for their existence in my "Port" table, it is actually faster for me to read my table in to a hash or pandas table rather than query the database every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your postgresql statement isn't problem, though you might shorten it a tad to this:

```
select exists(select from ref_locations where Port='ORAN');
```

The problem you're having is that the result of the execute statement isn't assigned to anything.

Consider trying this instead (after your execute statement):

```
exists = cnx.fetchone()
```

or just

```
print cnx.fetchone()
```

Answer (score 1):

Exists many variants, but simpliest is:

```
select count(*) > 0 from ref_locations where "Port"='ORAN'
```